# make the grouped items spin

Tags: html, svg, polygon

I am fiddling with SVG. I have a stopsign, and I've rotated it statically, but I want an animated spin. I've tried a few ways.. but I want to be able to just use the grouip that I made and make it spin.

I've tried nesting animateTransform in different ways.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SVG Sample - Transformations</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="html5.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <svg width="500" height="300">
          <defs> 
              <g id="myGroup"> 
                <polygon points="50,5   100,5  125,30  125,80 100,105
                50,105  25,80  25, 30"
                style="stroke:#747373; fill:#cc3333; stroke-width: 3;"/>

                <text x=40 y=65 font-family="san-serif" 
                font-size="30px" fill="white">
                    STOP
            </text>
             </g>
         </defs>



            <use xlink:href="#myGroup" 
                transform="translate(0,0)"></use>

            <use xlink:href="#myGroup" 
                transform="translate(250, -20) rotate(90)"></use> 

                <use xlink:href="#myGroup" 
                transform="translate(150, 220) rotate(180)"></use> 


                <use xlink:href="#myGroup" 
                transform="translate(150, 150) "
                <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                type="rotate"
                from="0 150 150"
                to="360 150 150"
                begin="0s"
                dur="1s"
                repeatCount="indefinite"
            />
                ></use> 

        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a typo: you need to close the `<use>` before the `<animateTransform>`. I.e: `<animateTransform>`should be a child of the animated element.

Comment: ahaaaaaaaaaaaa thank you. although now it is spinning in a wide arc instead of around the specified coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make it rotate around the center:`from="0 75 55" to="360 75 55"` and translate the whole thing:

```html
<svg width="500" height="300">
          <defs> 
              <g id="myGroup"> 
                <polygon points="50,5   100,5  125,30  125,80 100,105
                50,105  25,80  25, 30"
                style="stroke:#747373; fill:#cc3333; stroke-width: 3;"/>

                <text x=40 y=65 font-family="san-serif" 
                font-size="30px" fill="white">
                    STOP
            </text>
             </g>
         </defs>



            <use xlink:href="#myGroup" 
                transform="translate(0,0)"></use>

            <use xlink:href="#myGroup" 
                transform="translate(250, -20) rotate(90)"></use> 

                <use xlink:href="#myGroup" 
                transform="translate(150, 220) rotate(180)"></use> 

                <g transform="translate(120,110)">
                <use xlink:href="#myGroup">
                <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                type="rotate"
                from="0 75 55"
                to="360 75 55"
                begin="0s"
                dur="1s"
                repeatCount="indefinite"
            />
                </use> 
                </g>

        </svg>
```